# is threre any configuration to control permission to internet in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any configuration like android user-permission in iOS to control access to internet?

I think all new projects access to internet by default, is that correct?

When I send a request to the internet it returns 0 http-error code, it means I can't access to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is correct all the new ios project have access to the internet by default.
A status code of 0 in an NSHTTPURLResponse object generally means there was no response and can occur for various reasons. The server will never return a status of 0 as this is not a valid HTTP status code.

Answer (score 0):

Any http request will first be processed by the operating system, and during that phase you can get an *error*. Getting an error means that your request never got a response from the server (and with the exception of https requests where certificates were not accepted, most likely didn't reach the server).

If this phase succeeds, then you get eventually a reply from the server. This may take time, you may have to wait 60 seconds. Which is why you do all your internet requests on a background thread. That reply will have a *status* code (status, not error). The status code is NEVER 0.

By default, iOS doesn't allow http requests, and doesn't allow https requests to unsave servers, so you better use only https unless you have a very good reason. You will need a very good reason to convince Apple to let your app on the app store if you want http requests to succeed. But if you get this wrong, you get an error quite early on.

A status of zero most likely means that a background request didn't finish by the time you read the status, a basic programming mistake. You need to learn how background threads and callbacks work. Without that, you won't be able to use http successfully.

Also google for "Reachability" which can tell you if your app currently has internet access (like when WiFi and Mobile Data are turned off, or in Airplane mode).